# Removing backstretch image from pages/posts

Tags: php, responsive, custom-background

Homepage has a backstretch image which is also active throughout the site on posts and pages. How can I keep the backstretch on the homepage but hide it on posts or pages? pulled this from the functions.php thinking this might be where I'd need to start:

```
//* Load scripts only if custom backstretch image is being used
if ( ! empty( $image ) ) {

        wp_enqueue_script( 'theme-backstretch', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/js/backstretch.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'theme-backstretch-set', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ).'/js/backstretch-set.js' , array( 'jquery', 'theme-backstretch' ), '1.0.0' );

        wp_localize_script( 'theme-backstretch-set', 'BackStretchImg', array( 'src' => str_replace( 'http:', '', $image ) ) );

    }

}
```

Comment: You could add a conditional tag after the function `if ( is_front_page()`. Please ask this question on the SP forums as its not covered here on SE. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Brad! I use the SP forums, however I'm confused (and I'm totally new here so please correct me if I'm wrong) but isn't this a PHP question?

Comment: Hi Chris. Questions specifically relating to PHP code are also not covered. So are questions relating to the modification of commercial themes and plugins. Questions should relate specifically to WordPress. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: this is a WP specific question and is acceptable here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a conditional to the existing if-statement checking for `is_front_page()` (or `is_home()`, depending on your needs):

```
if ( ! empty( $image ) && is_front_page() ) {
```

Comment: You're quite welcome